# Simple explanation of finite time blowup of Navier stokes equations in 3 dimensional space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, regularity-theory-of-pdes

The problem of regularity of solution (existence, uniqueness, and finite energy) of Navier Stokes equations is interesting for some mathematicians. It is well-known that calculations show a finite time blowup where the velocity diverges to infinity.

I tried to follow some books or articles to find out where the blowup emerges but, due to mathematical technicalities I couldn't track the calculations.

So my question basically is that if anyone can explain it in simpler manner? 
Or if anyone can suggest a reference that simply explains this blowup phenomenon.

Any comment and answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Good question.  Not sure there is an easy abswer.

Comment: I know about different function spaces. Can you please suggest a reference that explains in somehow simpler form?

Comment: I would be glad to if I knew.  You might google up some papers. and see if you can find something easily understood.

Comment: It's well known that *It's not known* whether blowup actually occurs in Navier-Stokes - this is a million dollar problem! So what is your actual question? Are you asking what "blowup" means in this context?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I searched and found some books. I try to understand the method.

Comment: It is possible to exhibit the phenomenon of "blowup" in finite time with one-dimensional nonlinear DE's.  I think I would start with the one- and two-dimensional cases if I were looking to "explain it in simpler manner", rather than jumping in at the three-dimensional Navier-Stokes equations.

Comment: Thank you @hardmath. It's a very good suggestion. I'll check it out.